# Implementing a peeking iterator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm porting some code to Haskell that extensively uses the concept of
a peeking iterator. It essentially wraps a collection and provides two
functions, "next" and "peek". The "next" function advances the
iterator and returns the head element, while the "peek" function
returns the head element without advancing the iterator. What would be
an elegant way to translate this concept to Haskell? My best idea so
far is to basically use the State monad to keep track of the current
position of the iterator. Is there a cleaner way?

(I posted this on beginners@ too, but didn't get any answers)

Comment: Have you looked at the Data.Enumerator package. It comes with a peek function http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/enumerator/0.4.16/doc/html/Data-Enumerator.html

Comment: @ErikHinton - enumerators are probably extreme overkill given the problem description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of a side-effecting iterator is antithetical to the Haskell Way.  You could certainly whip up a monad, but at that point you're using Haskell as (to quote Simon PJ) the world's finest imperative language.

Without knowing more about the code you're trying to port, I can't give very specific advice, but here are my general thoughts:

- Implement your iteration using some kind of *fold*.
- The function that you pass to your fold operation should be *composed* of other functions.  Probably a composition of zero or more 'peeking' operations plus one 'nexting' operation.

If your fold expects something of type `a -> b -> a`, your `peek` and `next` versions probably both have this type, and you compose them like this:

```
peek_then_next :: (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> b -> a)

peek_then_next peek next = next'
  where next' a b = let a' = peek a b
                    in  next a' b
```

You'll see that both the `peek` and `next` arguments look at the same `b`, but the `peek` accumulates information into `a'` which is then seen by the `next` operation.

You compose as many of these as you like, then pass the composition to `foldl` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Usually in Haskell, instead of an iterator, you would compute an infinite list (typically generated by a recursive function). Instead of "getting elements out of" the iterator, you simply iterate down the list (typically using a recursive function, or a fold or map or something), and look at the elements in the list as you see fit. Because Haskell is lazy, it only computes values as you need them.

I think you should implement your task using a recursive function that takes the infinite list. To "peek", simply look at the first element of the list. (You can "peek" as many elements down past the current "head" of the list as you want, simply by indexing the list.) To "advance" the iterator, simply recursively call yourself with the tail of the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
type Iterator a = [a]

peek :: Iterator a -> a
peek = head

next :: Iterator a -> Iterator a
next = tail
```

What you describe sounds like Haskell's regular old built-in singly-linked List. Perhaps even a [zipper](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers).

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you want in Haskell, but be warned that these are heavy guns:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies  #-}

class Iterator as a | as -> a where
  peek :: as -> a
  next :: as -> (as, a)

--sample implementation  
instance Iterator [a] a where
  peek as = head as
  next as = (tail as, head as) 

--sample use
main = print $ next $ [3,4]
--([4],3)
```

Of course the `Iterator` doesn't change, it has to give back a new version of it (pretty similar to the random number generator), but I think something "mutable" would be overkill here.

That said, I think you should really use more idiomatic ways to do what you want in Haskell. Maybe you should look how the `Reader` monad works: http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#reader